# Get last values of each object in JSON response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, parsing

I'm looking for a way to parse a JSON response to **only get the days** in an array of dates.

Current JSON response:

```
 @result =  [2018-01-01, 2018-01-02, 2018-01-03, 2018-01-04]
```

`@result.last(2)` or equivalent for rails will naturally only get the two last dates in the entire array.

`result.slice(-2)` or equivalent for jQuery will unfortunately also only fetch me the last two dates in the entire array.

Desired parsing outcome:

```
[01, 02, 03, 04]
```

An answer for either jQuery or Rails would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain javascript for that.

```
var newResult = result.map(function(date) {
  return date.split('-')[2];
})
```

[MDN Documentation on the Array Map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Perfect. Should've known .map works for JSON as well. Will award this to you as determined by a coin-flip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression to match the last digits in your string:

```
/-(\d+)$/
```

You can then use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) on your `results` array to map each date to a day by using the above expression.

See example below:

```js
const result = ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04"],

days = result.map(day => day.match(/-(\d+)$/)[1]);
console.log(days);
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I awarded it to Travis as determined by a coinflip as both answers are equally worthy and you posted them basically exactly at the same time. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can also convert it to date and get the date and month and year respectively.
2. After getting append to array

```js
var result = ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04"];
var arr = [];
$.each(result, function(i, v) {
  var date = new Date(v);
  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  arr.push(day)
})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```